# Liferay: Getting the Organization Id for a top-level organization

Tags: liferay

I'm able to get the organizationId of regular organizations using the following code:

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = LiferayFacesContext.getInstance().getThemeDisplay();
long liferayOrganizationId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getOrganizationId();
```

But this code does not work for top-level orgs. How would I get the organizationId for a top-level organization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for top-level organizations as well. However, when you're using this in a site that is not associated to any organization, it will naturally not reveal a valid organization id.

Note that Liferay 6.1 now has sites, which contain all the pages. Organizations *can have* sites, but don't need to. Sites can well exist without any organization being associated with them. And that's when you get `0` as the organizationId result from the code in your question

Comment: That is exactly what I get. I have certain custom fields defined for a top-level organization. How would I get the values of those fields in this case? I mean, is there a getOrgByName() or something similar?

Comment: If you're working in a site (=scopeGroup) that does not belong to an organization, I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Do you want to access any generic (known by name) organization? You can use http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/OrganizationLocalService.html#getOrganization(long,%20java.lang.String) to get it, but in general I'm puzzled as of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: The link that you gave is what I used eventually. Basically, all my organizations have sites associated to them, except for the top-level org. So, my code was working everywhere except when at the main site that Liferay creates by default. This answer solved that problem. Thanks!